# Reading simple JSON Object returns undefined

Tags: jquery, json, object

I have a JSON object which looks like this.

```
  {
  "Manager": "[{\"firstname\":\"Kris\"}],[{\"lastname\":\"test\"}]",
  "Employee": "[{\"firstname\":\"Nick\"}],[{\"lastname\":\"test\"}]"
  }
```

I am using Jquery to try and read my object but it seems that I am doing a mistake somehow.

```
JSON.stringify(data[0].Manager.firstname) //returns undefined.
```

Any suggestions on how to read this via JQuery will be much appreciated

Please note my datatype is JSON on my ajax call. Thanks in advance.

Comment: is it `name` or `firstname`?

Comment: Sorry its firstname. I have edited my question.

Comment: use `'` instead of `\"`

Comment: Why are you double encoding your json?

Comment: this is not an object you have syntax error the object most look like: 
`{
  "Manager": "[{\"fistname\":\"Kris\"},{\"lastname\":\"test\"}]",
  "Employee": "[{\"fistname\":\"Nick\"},{\"lastname\":\"test\"}]"
  }` remove`][`between objects

Comment: This is how it comes from the back end. I am reading two columns from the database and I am storing them into a class where I have my object and properties. So when it comes to the ajax call and i alert `JSON.stringify(data)` it gives me the above result which I have not a big idea on how to read it as I am new into JSON objects.

Comment: Then the backend is broken. There's no reason for json to be encoded within json.

Comment: That's some messed up JSON it's returning.  Plus `firstname` is misspelled.

Comment: the object can not accept `key: [ ],[ ]` it can have only one `value`

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. I will have a look on the back end and find out why my data is coming in a bad format and I will update my question in case someone else faces the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

this is not valid json `"[{\"fistname\":\"Nick\"}],[{\"lastname\":\"test\"}]"`

is valid json `"[{\"fistname\":\"Nick\"},{\"lastname\":\"test\"}]"`

chack [json online](https://jsonlint.com/)

```js
var obj= {"Manager": "[{\"fistname\":\"Kris\"},{\"lastname\":\"test\"}]","Employee": "[{\"fistname\":\"Nick\"},{\"lastname\":\"test\"}]"};
  $.each(obj,function(key,value){
    if(key=='Manager'){
       var elem=$.parseJSON(value);
       $.each(elem,function(key,value){
         if(!(typeof value.fistname === "undefined"))
            console.log(value.fistname);
       });
     }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your json has fistName for the firstName. Changing it to firstName should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do json with js.

```js
var data = [{
    "Manager": {
      "firstname": "Kris",
      "lastname": "test"
    },
    "Employee": {
      "firstname": "Nick",
      "lastname": "test"
    }
  },
  {
    "Manager": {
      "firstname": "Kris2222",
      "lastname": "test222"
    },
    "Employee": {
      "firstname": "Nick222",
      "lastname": "test2222"
    }
  }
];



console.log(data[0].Manager.firstname);
console.log(data[1].Manager.firstname);
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel. I suppose I need to find out why my JSON object it comes messed up. I will let you know.

Comment: I know that this is the right way for a valid JSON object but it seems that there is an alternative of reading the object I have as per Farhad answer. I will try tomorrow and I ll come up with an edit.